# Wemos Mini & Pro Micro Serial connection

Tags: serial

While using a 3.3v Pro Mini & Wemos mini to communicate via Serial was successful, when tried with a 5v Pro Micro it fails.

To overcome different logic level I used a 10K + 20K resistors to lower Pro-Micro's 5v to 3.3v successfully to `Tx` and `Rx` pins. Also since they are on the same PCB, `GND` pins are connected and `RAW` to `5V` at wemos mini  is also connected. At the moment, it is powered up using MCU's USB input ( tried to connect to Pro-Micro only, Wemos Only, and both ).

[image: Schematics]
What might be the problem ?

Comment: It sounds like you have tried to put level shifting on both the TX and the RX pin. You want it *only* between the Arduino's TX pin and the ESP's RX pin. Not between the ESP's TX and Arduino's RX.

Comment: @Majenko see added schematic.

Comment: Yes, I thought you might have. ESP TX to Arduino RX needs to be a simple wire, nothing more.

Comment: Also you may find that your resistors are too high value. I use 1k/2k.

Comment: @Majenko - OK.. Now I get it :)

Comment: @Majenko - I followed an on-line tutorial :/

Comment: Yeah, you can never trust those online people. =)

Comment: @timemage - I see you are a keen follower for my endless mistakes ( Majenko 2 ) :)

Comment: @Majenko - to avoid my next question, as timemage suggested in my last question, when I2C between 3.3 and 5v - will I need a both resistors ?

Comment: For I2C you really want an active I2C level shifter. I2C is not push-pull like serial, but open drain. However you can probably just ignore it since the Arduino's internal pullup resistors will limit the current to such a tiny amount that the ESD diodes in the ESP8266 won't care (and there are somewhat unsubstantiated rumours that it's 5V tolerant anyway).

Comment: @Majenko - Jumpering 10K resistor did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Is your usb power coming from a computer?

Comment: @Majenko - Wrongly jumpered the Rx @ Pro-Micro. Now when Tx is has 10K and 20K and Rx is connected directly + Juraj's `Serial1` - Problem is now SOLVED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a logic level conversion between 5 V Micro Arduino and 3.3 V Wemos D1 mini. The 5 V ATmega 328p reads 3.3 V as HIGH and the esp8266 can tolerate 5 V logic level for tests. For long term connection you can add logic level conversion with a voltage divider to convert the 5 V of ATmega TX to 3.3 V of esp8266 RX.

RX/TX pins on Arduino Mini are Serial.
RX/TX pins on Arduino Micro are **Serial1**.
Serial is only USB on Micro.

Comment: But it has `Tx` and `Rx` actual pins, which are use `Serial.begib(9600)` the same way

Comment: This I know. Does it change Majenko’s answer?

Comment: @Guy.D, the logic level difference is not the problem. so I guessed you used the same sketch with Serial for Mini and Micro, instead of using Serial1 for Micro. you don't need to use level shifting for a test.

Comment: yes, same code was used.

Comment: @Guy.D, then I guessed right and that was the problem. for Micro use Serial1 to communicate with the Wemos

Comment: Changing to `Serial1` all `Serial` instances did not solve the problem. Nor Majenko's solution.

Comment: Nothing transferred... what / how would you suggest to try?

Comment: Only when applying Majenko's + your solutions, solved the problem. please update

Comment: Taking off the RX ( at PRO-Micro side ) side. It didn't work when it was installed